# AutoPostBack = true affect the date textbox changes

Tags: c#

I have the following component in my webpage:

```html
 <div class="formrows">
            <span class="fieldlable">Report Period:</span>
            <span>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxDateStart" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Text="<%# BindItem.DateStart %>" CssClass="textbox" /></span>
            <span>To:</span>
            <span>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxDateEnd" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Text="<%# BindItem.DateEnd %>" CssClass="textbox" /></span>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidatorStartDate"   Display="None" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please enter Start Date"  ValidationGroup="validate" ControlToValidate="TextBoxDateStart"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>    
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidatorEndDate"   Display="None" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please enter End Date" Text="" ValidationGroup="validate" ControlToValidate="TextBoxDateEnd"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>    
            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidatorStartDate" runat="server"   Display="None"  ErrorMessage="Please Start Date in the correct format (mm/dd/yyyy)" ValidationGroup="validate" ControlToValidate="TextBoxDateStart" ValidationExpression="(19|20)\d\d[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidatorEndDate" runat="server"   Display="None"  ErrorMessage="Please End Date in the correct format (mm/dd/yyyy)" ValidationGroup="validate" ControlToValidate="TextBoxDateEnd" ValidationExpression="(19|20)\d\d[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
            <asp:CustomValidator runat="server"  EnableClientScript="false" ID="valDateRange"  Display="None" ValidationGroup="validate" ControlToValidate="TextBoxDateStart" onservervalidate="valDateRange_ServerValidate" ErrorMessage="Start Date and End Date must within one month" />
            <asp:CustomValidator runat="server" EnableClientScript="false"  ID="CustomValidatorEndDate"  Display="None" ValidationGroup="validate" ControlToValidate="TextBoxDateEnd" onservervalidate="valEndDateRange_ServerValidate" ErrorMessage="Start Date must earlier than End Date" />

        </div>
            
         <div class="formrows">
            <span class="fieldlable">Country:</span>
            <span>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCountry" runat="server" DataTextField="Text" DataValueField="Value" AutoPostBack="true" SelectedIndex="<%# BindItem.CountryID %>" SelectMethod="LoadCountry"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCountry_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
            </span>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidatorCountry" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Country" ControlToValidate="ddlCountry"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>    

        </div>
```

For example,

When I write select the date 2017/02/01 for the date text box and then I select other Country, the date will change to the today date.

For the backend sourcecode, I already add in:

```
if (!IsPostBack == true)
{
    ...
```

But it made no effect at all.

May I know how to solve it?

Comment: What does your code do if `(!IsPostBack == true)` is true?

Comment: Hi can you please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42544678/edit) your question and add a [mcve]? What you have provided so far is insufficient for helping you without throwing random suggestions at you. For example, you backend source code for this component would be extremely useful. But please note that it needs to be *minimal*! We only need to the code that is causing the issue. Strip out the lines that are superfluous to the problem before posting.

Comment: You need to set the `ViewState` property of the date textboxes to true so it can remember the values between the round trips to the server.